# Woocommerce add to cart ajax function not updating without refreshing browser

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having issue with add to cart ajax functionality after Woocommerce plugin update. It does add product in the cart but do not show in the counter without refreshing a page. 
I have checked at server side there is no cache on.

Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you check with console are you getting the error over there or in the server error log?

Comment: yes i checked, There is no error in console.